# Get the next direction help provided GPS location

Tags: google-maps-api-3, gps, augmented-reality

I am working on proof of concept project that is an augmented reality based navigation system. Basically, it is supposed to provide users a video of real scene with additional navigational signs that are created with the use of GPS location.

The thing I need to do is not a complete useful system but rather a proof of concept. There were mainly two tasks that I had to do. First real image of the scene is processed to determine the road in it, and with the use of GPS I will place the navigational sign like turn right, go straight on the road. The challenge I have here is how i can fetch the required navigation information. I considered Google Maps Api but it requires you to have your google host. I also made some research about how to get directions from it, but it seems that results are not very well structured for my purposes. I mean I need something like having a certain number of outputs and rigorously defined (e.g. turn right, turn left, etc) but its output is very unstructured. How do you think I can achieve this task. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This Link might help for Google Map Location extraction 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview

You can use Layar , or other available AR sdks(Metaio, QUalcomm also provide one ) for AR related Overlays

Good luck !